# Eclipse RCP: Command visibleWhen for a dynamic List of Perspectives

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, perspective

I know I can make a Command visible in a menu for a certain perspective by specifying a `visibleWhen` element in the plugin XML:

```
<visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
    <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
        <equals value="myperspective"/>
    </with>
</visibleWhen>
```

But how can I make a Command visible for a list of perspectives? Moreover, can I use regular expressions or wildmarks to match a group of perspectives that might be added dynamically?

Alternatively, how can I use the `visibleWhen` element to *hide* the Command for a certain perspective?

Comment: Any reference? How can you link that in the application model? thanks. !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `<or>` element:

```
<with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
  <or>
    <equals value="myperspective"/>
    <equals value="myperspective2"/>
    .... more
  </or>
</with>
```

There is also `<not>` which can be used to exclude something.

There is no regular expression or wild card match. You could perhaps write a property tester using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` to do a match.

Comment: Very easy! I just tried having a `<not>` element with an `<or>` element with a list of perspectives - that doesn't seem to work. Does it? For that I guess I would need to write a property tester?